# Can I ask question about work politics and problems

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, allowed-topics, asking-questions

I am having some problems at work regarding habits, short temper and patterns which is effecting my work progress and want to discuss/find out a way to get out of this mental state and wonder if I can ask my question related to that on this website ?

Comment: You might find Workplace SE might be more appropriate

Comment: Or perhaps Productivity SE.

Comment: I tried looking at all sites for SO but I never seen these two, can you provide me link where I can see all of SO/SE sites please

Comment: @tereško You can find all the SE sites [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday), but Workplace is [here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) and Productivity is [here](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: [Cogsci](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com) might provide insight into specific psychology or social psych issues as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the nature of the concern it sounds like it might be a more appropriate fit for [Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) or [Productivity](http://productivity.stackexchange.com) than here on Philosophy.

However -- it perhaps bears mentioning that questions about the *philosophy* of labor are squarely on-topic -- for instance, questions about the meaning/sense of work; about the critical theory of labor and the larger social and political role work plays; about the implications of certain modes of work or industry for possibilities of life, or social/cognitive arrangements, and so on; etc.

Comment: And just in passing: SEP has a really interesting entry about feminist perspectives on class and work, which might be worth a look: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/feminism-class/